# Cannot read property 'send' of underfined

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, discord, discord.js

```js
const mudaeon = require('./mudaetime.json');
const cron = require('cron');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
 name: 'mudaetime',
 description: '...',
 execute(message, args) {
  if (mudaeon) {
   const channel = client.channels.cache.get('id');
   let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob(
    '* * * * *',
    () => {
     scheduledMessage.start();
    },
    message.react('✅'),
    channel.send('check $tu ! <@&id')
   );
  } else !mudaeon;
  {
   cancel();
  }
 },
};
```

Please help find the error in my code! I wanted to make a bot that sends a message in a specific channel every ten minutes (although in this case, I put it for every minute so I can see if it works)

Comment: make sure `'id'` is the actual identifier of the channel and not just the string `'id'`

Comment: yes! i changed it hear to 'id' but in the actual code there are numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new `Discord.Client()` instance, which does not share the same channels, members, roles, etc. as the original. Instead of creating a new `Discord.Client()`, you should pass the original one as an argument to your `execute()` function.

For example, you could change `async execute(message, args){` to `async execute(message, args, client){`. Then, in your command handler, change `command.execute(message, args)` to `command.execute(message, args, client)`

**However**, there is an even *easier* way. `client` is actually a valid property of the `message` object, referring to:

> The client that instantiated the message

([`Message#client` docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client))

So, instead of writing:

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('id');
```

You could write:

```js
const channel = message.client.channels.cache.get('id')
```

And it will work perfectly!

Comment: As a handy tip, you can get the corresponding `client` out of many objects like `message`. For example, `channel.client`, `role.client`, `member.client`, `reaction.client`, [the list](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/search?q=%23client) goes on.

Answer (score -1):

You should not use the cache to access the channels but the (async) `.fetch` method:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'mudaetime',
    description: '...',
    async execute(message, args){
        if(mudaeon){
            const channel = await client.channels.fetch('222109930545610754')
            let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob("* * * * *", () => {
                scheduledMessage.start()},
                message.react('✅'),
                channel.send("check $tu ! <@&id"))
        } else(!mudaeon);{
            cancel();
        }
    }
};
```

This should work better, a lot of methods are `async` in discord.js so becareful to properly `await` the values when calling such methods :)

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch

Comment: For this purpose, I don't think it really matters.

Comment: I tried this but i got the unhandled promise error, do you know why that could be

Comment: As @MinekoKayui said, both `.fetch()` and `.cache.get()` will do the exact same thing in this situation.