# What is the reason for giving this error: cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I can't understand what's wrong.

**Note:** I am a beginner.

**Nothing returns for me on**: `client.channels.get`

**My code:**

```
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
message.channel.send(`Olá <@&702918917588385858>`)

}

client.channels.get("780108435940835378").send();
```

Comment: Small nitpick, and definitely outside the scope of your question as you've phrased it, but I strongly believe `message.delete().catch(O_o => {});` is poor practice - you really should be properly catching and handling your exceptions.

Comment: Try `client.channels.cache.get` instead of `client.channels.get` -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60667394/600135

Comment: Some clarifying questions, more to the point of your initial inquiry: (1) Can you share specifically on which line you're encountering the error you posted? You have two distinct calls to `send()`. (2) Which version of the Discord.JS are you using? The latest version made some very large changes to the way `client.channels` is returned. (3) Have you actually logged your client in? Unless I'm missing something here, not seeing this functionality that would be required to retrieve a channel listing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'send' of underfined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63666855/cannot-read-property-send-of-underfined)

Comment: @kol Eu tentei e apareceu: cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: @esqew 
(1) Does not point out the error
(2) v11
(3) Do not know

Answer (score 0):

It means that `channel` is `undefined`. It looks like you're expecting `message` to be an object containing a property called `channel` but that is not the case evidently.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer that question without any context, but all I can say here, is that you are trying to call the *send* method on an undefined object.

Are you sure that `client.channels.get("780108435940835378")` returns something?

Comment: Yes. The purpose of my code is for me to enter a command and it will send a message to a channel

Comment: Worth noting that Discord.JS' support for this method signature was removed in v12 - `client.channels` is now no longer a `Collection` object, but rather was replaced with a new [`ChannelManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/ChannelManager) object, which has a **completely** different prototype.

Comment: @LuizFilipe That's great and all, however can you elaborate on *how* you know `client.channels.get()` is returning something?

Comment: I don't use v12, I use v11

Comment: I'm Brazilian so sometimes I don't understand you well, however, nothing is returned

Comment: @LuizFilipe This is particularly pertinent information - can you please edit the body of your question with both of these facts? They will help others immensely, both for those who are seeking to help you with an answer, as well as future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 0):

client.channels is a `ChannelManager`, not a `Collection`. The channels are found at client.channels.cache. Perhaps use client.channels.fetch() first to ensure they are cached.
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager

client.channels.cache *is* a `Collection`, and has a method `get()`.
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection

Comment: Because I'm inexperienced and Brazilian, I don't understand English very well, could you be a little understandable please?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you really mind being replied to in Portuguese you could always use [Portuguese Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) although response times may vary.

Anyway, there are two main problems with your code. First, you're creating another instance of a Discord Client in this command file which will not be the same in which your bot is running in the main/index file (the one in which you used `client.login(token)`, [you could get a better explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63666855/cannot-read-property-send-of-underfined)) and second, your send command is out of the run function block, it should be inside.

To solve this, if the message argument in your run function is a `Message` Object you could get the client from the client property in the message object. So your command may look like this:

```js
module.exports.run = function(bot, message, args) {
  const client = message.client;
  // The channel you want to send the message in.
  // If it always the one in which the message was
  // sent you could use message.channel
  const channel == client.channels.get('YOUR_CHANNEL_ID_HERE');

  message.delete();
  message.channel.send(`Olá, ${message.user.toString()}!`);
  channel.send('Anything you want / Qualquer coisa.');
}
```