# Bot says that it is in 0 servers, with 0 channels, with 0 users

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a `&bot-info` command but every time I use it, it says it is on 0 servers, with 0 channels with 0 users, how would I fix this issue? I have a similar line of code in the begining when the bot turns on telling me the amount of servers ,channels and users hes in and it works fine

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js')
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    async function execute(message, args) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            
            .setTitle('Bot Stats')
            .setColor('#000000')
            .addFields(
                {
                    name: ' Servers',
                    value: `Serving ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers.`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: ' Channels',
                    value: `Serving ${client.channels.cache.size} channels.`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: ' Server Users',
                    value: `Serving ${client.users.cache.size}`,
                    inline: true
                }
            )
            

        await message.channel.send(embed)
    }
module.exports = {
    name: 'bot-info',
    description: 'bot information',
    execute
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'send' of underfined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63666855/cannot-read-property-send-of-underfined)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adjust this simple solution for your code, which worked for me, or give more details why do you want to use the async function.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.content === "&bot-info") {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
            .setTitle('Bot Stats')
            .setColor('#000000')
            .addFields(
                {
                    name: ' Servers',
                    value: `Serving ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers.`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: ' Channels',
                    value: `Serving ${client.channels.cache.size} channels.`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: ' Server Users',
                    value: `Serving ${client.users.cache.size}`,
                    inline: true
                }
            )
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem Here Is The Guilds.cache only works on index.js for some reason I tried doing the same thing on my command handler but still it's saying 0 for me to so if you want it to work put this command in your index.js or bot.js